mod_rewrite rules to strip body content when using HTTP HEAD request
I experimented with some sites including my own using CURL.
When you request a website with a HEAD request, its supposed to return only the HTTP headers, whereas a GET request, it also returns the body.
I'm trying to make a rewrite rule in my .htaccess that would strip the entire body buy leave the headers generated by scripts and earlier .htaccess rules in tact.
Here's the code so far:
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD) [NC]
RewriteRule .* aaa.htm [L,S=9999]

So I tested that, and added a blank aaa.htm file in document root. While the body is correct (returns nothing), the HTTP headers are not correct.
I also tried changing:
RewriteRule .* aaa.htm [L,S=9999]

to:
RewriteRule .* - [L,S=9999]

and that did not help.
How do I fix this with .htaccess?
